# Use header in BIRT report to sort data at the client side (with JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, sorting, birt

I want to add to the BIRT table and crosstab controls the following functionality: when I click on the header of a specific column, the data get sorted according to this column in the ascending or descending order.

I found [this trick](http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/files/file/1021-dynamic-column-sorting/) that uses parameters to sort the data on the server side, but I don't want to work the sorting on the server side. However, I want to do it in the client side preferably with JavaScript.

Please, any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually i embed [Datatables](https://www.datatables.net/) for this. It is simple, powerful and it has a good documentation.

You can visit a live demo of a [BIRT table with Datatable here](http://www.visioneo.org/interactive-birt-table). As you can see, all drillthrough hyperlink actions and styles are kept intact.

Basically we need to add a HTML text at the end of the report, set the type to "HTML" and load jquery and datatable in a script tag using "head.js". For instance:

```
<script>

head.load("//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css","//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js",function(){
    console.log("DataTables framework loaded...");
    $("#myTableID").DataTable();  //"myTableID" should be the bookmark of the table
    console.log("Interactive table is ready!"); 
});

</script>
```

[image]

Use BIRT bookmark property to set an ID to the table. Please notice if your BIRT emitter does not generate a "thead" tag inside the HTML table (just inspect the html output to see if a thead tag is generated or not), you need to fix it by script: move the first row under "tbody" into a "thead" tag using jquery, before invoking "DataTable()" function. Indeed it requires a little bit of javascript knowledge but as you see that will be well worth it!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to know more about the code that you have posted <script>...</script>, have I to copy and paste it in the xml part of the report just before </report>? Anyway, that did not work for me.. Any hints where can I place it exactly?

Comment: I have other questions: what should I write in the head.js file?  How can I know if my BIRT emitter does or not generate the thead? Any hints please?

Comment: This code has to be put in a BIRT text element inserted after the table, and having its type set to "HTML". I edited the answer to add a screenshot. Furthermore it appears "head.load" works better for multiple JS dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, so much appreciated!

So, is the bookmark id the id of the resultant HTML page. That means the HTML page output should have a table with "myTableID" id if I fixed the bookmark correctly?

Another thing, all the generated tables in the HTML page output are with tags "TD" and "TR" tags, not all the "thead" and "tbody" tags. So have I to change these tags using JavaScript or I have only to change the first row of table to the <thead>? Please any hints?

Comment: This is correct: BIRT is setting the bookmark value to HTML id for any report element, including tables. Datatables need a "thead" tag to work properly: if you inspect the native BIRT html output with Chrome, normally all "TR" tags should be arranged under a "tbody" tag. Create a "thead" with javascript at the same level as 'tbody" (just under the table root in fact), and move the first "TR" tag of the body in this header, and you should be done.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! unfortunately, no tbody tags at all! as I told you only the tags <TR> and <TD> under the <table> tag. Does that mean something wrong in my generated report? Another thing, just to check if I am getting the bookmark trick correctly. I have to set up the bookmark property of the table as  "myTableID" and that's it. No any other expressions or coding, isn't?

Comment: That's it: set "myTableID" in bookmark property, and don't forget to surround it with double-quotes otherwise BIRT would try to evaluate it as a variable. Concerning tbody tag, you are right BIRT does not generate it but anyway it is automatically included by web-browsers when not found. So you just need to focus on thead tag

Comment: Thanks! now it worked for me but I had to change the link for the datatable library and add the thead (for the first row) as you told me. Now, I want to mention that the birt paging is not working an more. So, do u know any trick to make it work for datatables?

Comment: Assuming you make use of eclipse web viewer, this is a variable conflict:  both jquery and eclipse birt viewer share "$" as a variable name. To avoid this you need to use "noConflict" function just after loading jquery. For example store jquery in a new variable, and then use this var in script instead of "$" :  var $jq=jQuery.noConflict();     https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: It worked, but I have another problem now. The sorting is only applicable on the last page. The first pages are displayed as a non datatable table... Please any hints?

Comment: Anyway, to solve this issue, I placed the script inside the table (in the first cell of the table). But, what I noticied is that the sorting effect is applied only on the current page and not on the whole data. So please, Is there any trick to make the datatable applicable on the whole data and NOT on the data of the current page of the table?

Comment: Actually you want to disable pagination of this table in Eclipse. Set a page break interval to 0 (or a high value such 10000) and you should be done.

Comment: That's true, that solves the issue.. But still does not look very "good" as there will be two paging functionalities (one for birt and one for the datatable) which is pretty confusing for my client that has used the paging functionalities in birt... Thanks anyway..

Comment: I have followed all the above steps. but data tables not loaded and not working.